# Correct usage of JPA criteria API, Predicates and where method of CriteriaQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am trying to test a JPA repository. Here is my client/test code:

```
@Test
    public void testFindBoitesByMultiFieldWithIdentifiantSet() {
        BoiteDataOnDemand dod = new BoiteDataOnDemand();
        Boite boite = dod.getSpecificBoite(0);
        boite.setIdentifiant("theIdentifiant");
        boiteRepository.save(boite);
        assertEquals(10, Boite.countBoites());
        BoiteQueryInfo boiteQueryInfo = new BoiteQueryInfo();
        boiteQueryInfo.setIdentifiant("theIdentifiant");
        List<Boite> boites = boiteRepository.findBoitesByMultiField(boiteQueryInfo, 1, 5, "identifiant", "desc");
        assertEquals(1, boites.size());
    }
```

Here is the repository method:

```
@Override
    public List<Boite> findBoitesByMultiField(BoiteQueryInfo boiteQueryInfo, Integer firstResult_, Integer maxResults_, String sort_, String order_) {
        log.debug("findBoitesByMultiField");

        final String identifiant = boiteQueryInfo.getIdentifiant();
        final Date dateOuvertureFrom = boiteQueryInfo.getDateOuvertureFrom();

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Boite> c = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Boite.class);
        Root<Boite> boite = c.from(Boite.class);
        List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            ...
        if (identifiant != null && !identifiant.trim().equals("")) {
            ParameterExpression<String> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class, "identifiant");
            Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.like(boite.<String> get("identifiant"), parameter);
            criteria.add(condition);
        }

        if (dateOuvertureFrom != null && dateOuvertureTo != null) {
            ParameterExpression<Date> parameterDateOuvertureFrom = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class, "dateOuvertureFrom");
            ParameterExpression<Date> parameterDateOuvertureTo = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class, "dateOuvertureTo");
            Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.between(boite.<Date> get("dateOuverture"), parameterDateOuvertureFrom, parameterDateOuvertureTo);
            criteria.add(condition);
        } else if (dateOuvertureFrom != null) {
            ParameterExpression<Date> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class, "dateOuvertureFrom");
            Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(boite.<Date> get("dateOuverture"), parameter);
            criteria.add(condition);
        } else if (dateOuvertureTo != null) {
            ParameterExpression<Date> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class, "dateOuvertureTo");
            Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(boite.<Date> get("dateOuverture"), parameter);
            criteria.add(condition);
        }

            ...    
        if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("desc")) {
            c.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(boite.get(sort)));
        } else {
            c.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(boite.get(sort)));
        }

        for (Predicate predicate : criteria) {
            c.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicate));
        }

        TypedQuery<Boite> q = em.createQuery(c);

        if (identifiant != null && !identifiant.trim().equals("")) {
            q.setParameter("identifiant", "%" + identifiant + "%");
        }

        if (dateOuvertureFrom != null && dateOuvertureTo != null) {
            q.setParameter("dateOuvertureFrom", dateOuvertureFrom);
            q.setParameter("dateOuvertureTo", dateOuvertureTo);
        } else if (dateOuvertureFrom != null) {
            q.setParameter("dateOuvertureFrom", dateOuvertureFrom);
        } else if (dateOuvertureTo != null) {
            q.setParameter("dateOuvertureTo", dateOuvertureTo);
        }

            ...    
        return q.setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
    }
```

However, the test always fails at **`assertEquals(1, boites.size());`** indicating that no result is returned i.e. (`java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<0>`).

I strongly suspect something is wrong here:

```
for (Predicate predicate : criteria) {
            c.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicate));
        }
```

But I am not sure how to "and" the criteria.

Can anyone please provide advice?

P.S. FYI, `BoiteDataOnDemand` inserts random 10 rows into the `boite` table.

EDIT: code was edited to make it shorter.

Comment: The code you have posted is much too long. Please only post the relevant parts of it.

Comment: I gave up on JPA's criteria API. QueryDSL with its fluent API is much simpler to understand and more concise. See: [queryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/documentation)

Answer (score 27):

Starting from your hint in the final part of your post, I agree that the way you are adding predicates for the `where` clause is not correct.

I see two ways of proceeding:

**First way**

Using an array of predicates

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
for (Key key : keys) {
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(key), value));
}
c.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
```

**Second way**

Modifying the same predicate in the loop

```
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
for (Key key : keys) {
    Predicate newPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(key), value);
    predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, newPredicate);
}
c.where(predicate);
```

---

EDITED

After looking again your code sample, I see that you have already created in the correct way a list of `Predicate`S: you have called it `criteria`. You are only using them in the wrong way. See the last line of my first example.

---

EDIT 2

In order to see if the problem is generated by the use of `PredicateExpressionS`, that are not specifically needed in your case, try to temporarily remove them. Modify your first criteria from

```
if (identifiant != null && !identifiant.trim().equals("")) {
    ParameterExpression<String> parameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class, "identifiant");
    Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.like(boite.<String> get("identifiant"), parameter);
    criteria.add(condition);
}
```

to

```
if (identifiant != null && !identifiant.trim().equals("")) {
    Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.like(boite.get("identifiant"), "%" + identifiant + "%");
    criteria.add(condition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Perissf. Can you please tell me the type and value for the `value` variable? Regards.

Comment: That was just pseudo-code. You can use your Predicates instead. You will probably not use the loop but the concept is valid anyway for your `if` clauses. Hope it's clear.

Comment: The behavior of my test is the same after using the last line of your code i.e. `c.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));` Any other idea?

Comment: I've altered the code as advised in your second edit as well as commented out the following line: `q.setParameter("identifiant", "%" + identifiant + "%");` It makes no difference unfortunately...

Comment: I think that: c.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));is redundant as it could be rewritten as: c.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

Answer (score 2):

The complete solution that work for me is the following:

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
        Root<Eje> ejeRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Eje.class);
        Root<FactorCritico> factorRoot = criteriaQuery.from(FactorCritico.class);


        int factorParam = 2;

        criteriaQuery.multiselect(ejeRoot,factorRoot);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        Predicate ejeJoinFactorCritico = builder.equal(ejeRoot.get("id"), factorRoot.get("eje"));
        predicates.add(ejeJoinFactorCritico);   

        if (factorParam> 0){
            Predicate factorFilter = builder.equal(factorRoot.get("id"), factorParam);
            predicates.add(factorFilter);   
        }

        criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));

        Query<Object[]> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();

        for(Object[] objects: resultList){
            Eje eje = (Eje) objects[0];
            System.out.println("eje: "+eje.getName());

            FactorCritico factor= (FactorCritico) objects[1];
            System.out.println("--> factor: "+factor.getName()+ ", eje: "+ factor.getEje().getName());

            //System.out.println("eje, factor size = "+eje.getFactorCriticos());
        }
```

Comment: Explanation to large code block would be helpful for future readers

Comment: I have a variable "factorParam' used as a flag, if it variable is greater than zero then a Predicate object is added to an Predicate list object, after that, the list predicate is added to where sentence.