# How to generate dynamic query strung together using OR using JPA?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria-api

Need to generate a query like so using JPA. It needs to be dynamic because I don't know till runtime what parameters I'd get.

SQL I'd like from JPA:

select * from foo where a='A' OR b='B' OR c='C' OR (x='X' AND y='Y')

- Don't know ahead of time if any of 'A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'Y' will be
  provided.
- X and Y should always use 'AND'.
- If one of the    inputs is missing, example, if C is not provided, we should simply eliminate that - query becomes - "select * from foo where a='A' OR b='B' OR (x='X' AND y='Y')

Most of the examples I've come across using JPA are simply using the AND operator when a query is dynamically generated. Either that, or, they are doing it statically using "criteriabuilder.or(..., ..., ...). That won't work in my case.

Comment: What's wrong with the `CriteriaBuilder`? I don't quite understand. `or` takes a varargs argument so can easily be an array of any length. Build a `List` of your restrictions and then use `toArray()` to pass it in.

Comment: Try to get some hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12245277/870122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [`CriteriaBilder#disjunction()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction%28%29) operator in order to build a Predicate to be dynamically modified:

```
Integer aValue, xValue, yValue;
Predicate p = cb.disjunction();
if (aValue != null) {
    p = cb.or(p, cb.equal(foo.get("a"), aValue));
}
...
if (xValue != null && yValue != null) {
    p = cb.or(p, cb.and(cb.equal(foo.get("x"), xValue), cb.equal(foo.get("y"), yValue)));
}
```

Or use an array of predicates:

```
List<Predicate> predicateArray = new ArrayList<> ();
if (aValue != null) {
    predicateArray.add(cb.equal(foo.get("a"), aValue));
}
...
if (xValue != null && yValue != null) {
    predicateArray.add(cb.and(cb.equal(foo.get("x"), xValue), cb.equal(foo.get("y"), yValue)));
}
Predicate p = cb.or(predicateArray.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query storing that in a String variable where you can append several parts of that respect some condition.

An example:

```
// This part is always presents
String hql = " SELECT * FROM foo ";
String whereClause = " where ";
String whereCond = "";

if (condition on A is satisfacted) {
    whereCond += "a = 'A'";
}

if (condition on B is satisfacted) {
    if (!whereCond.equals("")) {
        whereCond += " or ";
    }
    whereCond += "b = 'B'";
}

... AND GO ON ...

At the end

String res = hql;
if (!whereCond.equals("")) {
   res += whereClause + whereCond;
}

return res;
```

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: You could also build a `List` of criteria and join them on ` or `, which would be much more readable and less error prone. In any case, the is the sort of thing the `CriteriaBuilder` is designed for; building dynamic queries. So its best to use that rather than invent polygonal wheels.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Yes, the CriteriaBuilder does the same thing, I prefer this style, for me is more readable than CriteriaBuilder

Comment: @BoristheSpider - How is it done with CriteriaBuilder? I don't believe  the string based approach is acceptable to the team. I did trying joining by "OR" but starting with "criteriabuilder.or(...)" is adding a "where 1=1 OR ..." in the beginning which ends up selecting the whole database

Comment: @BVSat maybe if you posted up your attempt then it would be a start.